# Get contents of a div with mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to figure out how to get the contents of a div by its selector, does anyone have any code please, for example

1

I would like to get the one from the div element

Comment: Do you mean get the HTML content of a div element ? Or get the elements inside the div element by selectors?

Comment: Just learn how to read a [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element).

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. I think, you have not read [Mootools documentations here](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element).

```
var myElement = document.id('myElement');
var myElement = document.id(el);
```